# Qt DBus registerService function call returns false on an embedded Linux device

Tags: qt, embedded-linux, dbus

I’m new to DBus, but I’m trying to use it in two Qt applications on an embedded device. I have a very simple interface that consists of one slot:

```
QString SendMessage(const QString &cmd);
```

The server application is then using the following code to start the connection:

```
    DbusService* dBus = new DbusService;
    new interfaceIfAdaptor(dBus);
 
    QDBusConnection connection = QDBusConnection::sessionBus();
    bool ret = connection.registerService("com.domain.project.interface");
    qDebug() << "returns" << ret;
    ret = connection.registerObject("/", dBus);
    qDebug() << "returns" << ret;
```

**This works fine on the desktop**. In the embedded system, the connection.registerService function returns false. As a result, any messages to the server fail. I’m not sure why. Running ‘ps’ tells me that [dbus-daemon —system] and [dbus-daemon —sesson] are both running.

Finally, I have noticed that Qt Creator complains when I debug the application. I see the following warning messages:

> Could not load shared library symbols for 10 libraries, e.g. /opt/arm/lib/libQtDBus.so.4.
>
> Use the “info sharedlibrary” command to see the complete listing.
>
> Do you need “set solib-search-path” or “set sysroot”?
>
> Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/lib/libdbus-1.so.3.
>
> Do you need “set solib-search-path” or “set sysroot”?

If additional information is required to debug this problem, please let me know. Or if there are useful dbus commands I could run to help figure this out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the session bus was not getting started on the device.  I enabled it, but then I ran into the problem of the address not getting propagated to the environment variables.  I can manually set it in a terminal, but I'm not sure how to do the same in Qt Creator.

Anyway, rather than spend more time figuring out the issues with the session bus, I switched to using the system bus.  I just had to change the /etc/dbus-1/system.conf file to allow anyone to talk to the system bus and my applications work on the embedded device.  I know that's probably not the long term solution, but it works for now.

Comment: I've been caught out by this one before too. The session bus is created on login.  In fact, `dbus-launch` is *the* script that is run by the login process.  
There might be an argument that whatever is running on your embedded system without a login is a daemon, and therefore should be making use of the system bus.